# Can I get vi to set expandtab wisely, itself?

Tags: vim, automation, tabs, indentation, vi

I sometimes edit source files with tab indentation, and sometimes with spaces, with vi(m).

In a tabs file, I don't want expandtab - I need actual tabs; in a spaces file - I need expandtab to get spaces.

But - I'm lazy, I don't want to have to set one of these myself each time I start editing a file.

Is there a way to get vi(m) to decide what to seet expandtab to based on the contents of the file, automagically?

Comment: Ask google about "vim-sleuth" and/or "editorconfig".

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by programming vim accordingly; but instead of doing it yourself, use a plugin with this functionality.

For example: [vim-sleuth](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth):

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack/tpope/start
cd ~/.vim/pack/tpope/start
git clone https://tpope.io/vim/sleuth.git
vim -u NONE -c "helptags sleuth/doc" -c q
```

What it does is run on vim's BufNewFile, BufReadPost, and
BufFilePost events firing, and try to figure out settings for `expandtab` and `shiftwidth`. It consults the file's modeline, then looks at the current file's choice of spaces-vs-tabs and how many spaces to use for each indentation.